# K-groups of strict henselization of stalks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory

How well are the algebraic K-groups of the strict henselization of the stalks $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}^{sh}$ at geometric points of a scheme $X$ understood? I am particularly interested in the case of rational K-theory and when $X$ is a smooth projective scheme over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: If you mean $K$-theory of strictly Henselian local rings I don't quite understand what does that have to do with the ambient scheme. Or do you want to know how do these vary from point to point, what kind of sheaf does one get from them, etc.?

Comment: You should look at Gabber, K -theory of Henselian local rings and Henselian pairs.

Answer (score 3):

As remarked in the comment of Donu Arapura, the K-theory with finite coefficients (or even completed at some prime) can be understood using the rigidity theorems of Suslin and Gabber. These state that the projection $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{sh}\to\kappa(x)$ from the strictly henselian local ring to its residue field induces an isomorphism on K-theory with finite coefficients. This reduces the question to algebraically closed fields in characteristic $p$, but the rigidity theorem also tells us that inclusions of algebraically closed fields induce isomorphisms on K-theory with finite coefficients. With finite coefficients, we thus know a complete answer (because we know the K-theory of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ from Quillen's computations).

With rational coefficients, however, K-theory is not understood, as far as I know. The rigidity theorems are no longer true (which can already be seen on $K_1$). Already the special case of the K-theory of algebraic closures of function fields of varieties in characteristic $p$ is unclear; we don't know $K_\bullet(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q(T_1,\dots,T_n)})\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ for $n>2$. For $n=1$, we can approximate $K_\bullet(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q(T)})$ as a filtered colimit of $K_\bullet(\mathbb{F}_q[C_i])$ where $C_i$ runs through smooth curve models of finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q(T)$. Then by the work of Harder, we know that the K-groups $K_i(\mathbb{F}_q[C])$ of these curves are torsion for $i>1$. Passing to the colimit, we see that the rational K-groups of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q(T)}$ vanish in degrees $>1$. In degree 1, we just have $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q(T)}^\times\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$.

There is also Parshin's conjecture on vanishing of K-theory, but that concerns smooth projective varieties, so it doesn't immediately say much about the K-theory of function fields of varieties. Maybe one could use a localization argument to inductively deduce from Parshin's conjecture and the curve case that the rational K-theory of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q(T_1,\dots,T_n)}$ vanishes in degrees $>n$, but I haven't checked that properly.